# Space of regular maps from the spectrum of a field to a variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Given two varieties over complex numbers denoted by $X$ and $Y$ you can look at the space of regular maps from $X$ to $Y$ as a subspace of continuous maps and hence $Map_{reg}(X,Y)$ becomes a topological space. The case I am interested in is when $X$ is actually a scheme which is the spectrum of a field of pure transcendental degree $n$ over $\mathbb{C}$ denoted by $F_n$. In other words $F_n$ is the function field of $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$. Now you can make sense of the topological space $Maps_{reg}(\text{Spec}(F_n), Y)$ as the colimit of $Maps_{reg}(U, Y)$ over $U$ which varies over Zariski open subschemes of $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ with the direct limit topology.

Is there a more direct way to understand this space? My attempt was to just look at the algebraic maps from $\text{Spec}(F_n)$ to $Y$. It seems to me that giving a such map amounts to determining a rational subvariety of $Y$ of dimension $m\leq n$ together with a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra morphism $F_m\rightarrow F_n$. I have no idea what the space of rational subvarieties or the space of the aforementioned $\mathbb{C}$-algebra morphisms look like and what are the correct topologies on them and how do they relate to $Maps_{reg}(\text{Spec}(F_n), Y)$ defined in the first paragraph. Can this space be explained using some well-known spaces/moduli spaces? I am also fine even if $Y$ is just the projective space.

Comment: Why bother with open subschemes?  Spec of a field is a single point so there isn't any nontrivial subschemes of $X=\operatorname{Spec}(F_n)$.

Comment: @user10354138 It is to define a topology on the mapping space. Without that I don't know how look at the maps from $\text{Spec}(F_n)$ to $Y$ as a topological space. Colimit is taken over the subschemes of $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ not the Spec of a field. That's a typo.